# Rails connect to SQL Server 2008 by activerecord-sqlserver-adapter

Tags: activerecord, jruby

I downloaded BitNami's Jruby. Everything is OK, but when I want to connect to SQL Server 2008, something is wrong.

The database.yml is follows

```
development:
       adapter: sqlserver
      host: 127.0.0.1
      instanceName: SQLServer2008
      database: truetemp
      username: sa
      password: 7354500
```

I use command "Jruby -S rails generate scaffold Product title:string ....", ROR works well;
but the command "rake db:migrate --trace" fails.

> f:\tmp\RubyMine201207>rake db:migrate --trace
>   ** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
>   ** Invoke environment (first_time)
>   ** Execute environment
>   ** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
>   ** Invoke rails_env (first_time)
>   ** Execute rails_env
>   ** Execute db:load_config rake aborted! Please install the sqlserver adapter: `gem install activerecord-sqlserver-adapte r` (no such file
>   to load -- active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter)
>
> org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1033:in `require' F:/Program Files/BitNami
>   JRubyStack/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3
>   .2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in`require' F:/Program
>   Files/BitNami JRubyStack/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3
>   .2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
>   F:/Program Files/BitNami
>   JRubyStack/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3
>   .2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in`require' F:/Program
>   Files/BitNami JRubyStack/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.
>   2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:4
>   8:in `resolve_hash_connection' F:/Program Files/BitNami
>   JRubyStack/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.
>   2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:3
>   9:in`resolve_string_connection' F:/Program Files/BitNami
>   JRubyStack/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.
>   2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:2
>   3:in `spec' F:/Program Files/BitNami
>   JRubyStack/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.
>   2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:1
>   27:in`establish_connection' F:/Program Files/BitNami
>   JRubyStack/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.
>   2.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:76:in `Railtie' org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2045:in`instance_eval' F:/Program
>   Files/BitNami JRubyStack/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3
>   .2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
>   F:/Program Files/BitNami
>   JRubyStack/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3
>   .2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in`run_load_hooks'
>   org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1615:in `each' F:/Program Files/BitNami
>   JRubyStack/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3
>   .2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in`run_load_hooks'
>   F:/Program Files/BitNami
>   JRubyStack/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.
>   2.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:716:in `(root)' F:/Program Files/BitNami JRubyStack/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.
>   2.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:6:in`(root)' org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call' org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in`
>   call' F:/Program Files/BitNami
>   JRubyStack/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/li
>   b/rake/task.rb:205:in `execute' org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1615:in`
>   each' F:/Program Files/BitNami
>   JRubyStack/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/li
>   b/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute' F:/Program Files/BitNami
>   JRubyStack/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/li
>   b/rake/task.rb:158:in`invoke_with_call_chain' F:/Program
>   Files/BitNami JRubyStack/jruby/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:191:in `mon_sy
>   nchronize' F:/Program Files/BitNami
>   JRubyStack/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/li
>   b/rake/task.rb:151:in`invoke_with_call_chain' F:/Program
>   Files/BitNami JRubyStack/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/li
>   b/rake/task.rb:176:in `invoke_prerequisites'
>   org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1615:in`each' F:/Program Files/BitNami
>   JRubyStack/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/li
>   b/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites' F:/Program Files/BitNami
>   JRubyStack/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/li
>   b/rake/task.rb:157:in`invoke_with_call_chain' F:/Program
>   Files/BitNami JRubyStack/jruby/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:191:in `mon_sy
>   nchronize' F:/Program Files/BitNami
>   JRubyStack/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/li
>   b/rake/task.rb:151:in`invoke_with_call_chain' F:/Program
>   Files/BitNami JRubyStack/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/li
>   b/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke' F:/Program Files/BitNami
>   JRubyStack/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/li
>   b/rake/application.rb:116:in`invoke_task' F:/Program Files/BitNami
>   JRubyStack/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/li
>   b/rake/application.rb:94:in `top_level'
>   org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1615:in`each' F:/Program Files/BitNami
>   JRubyStack/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/li
>   b/rake/application.rb:94:in `top_level' F:/Program Files/BitNami
>   JRubyStack/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/li
>   b/rake/application.rb:133:in`standard_exception_handling' F:/Program
>   Files/BitNami JRubyStack/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/li
>   b/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level' F:/Program Files/BitNami
>   JRubyStack/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/li
>   b/rake/application.rb:66:in`run' F:/Program Files/BitNami
>   JRubyStack/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/li
>   b/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling' F:/Program
>   Files/BitNami JRubyStack/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/li
>   b/rake/application.rb:63:in`run' F:/Program Files/BitNami
>   JRubyStack/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bi n/rake:33:in
>   `(root)' org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1058:in`load' F:/Program
>   Files/BitNami JRubyStack/jruby/bin/rake:23:in `(root)' Tasks: TOP =>
>   db:migrate => db:load_config

Comment: My English is not good. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you add the following line to your `Gemfile`

`gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter'`

Comment: Thank Chris Ledet! This is my first question at StackOverFlow, exciting!